# How would you get a "sun" to orbit a "rogue planet"?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, space-constructs

So let's say I have rogue planet the size of mars.
I want seasons roughly the the same as Earth and a "sun" that appears similar to our sun from the surface.

How big would the Star need to be?
How far away from the planet would it have to orbit?

I also want a moon. I'm thinking maybe 2 bodies of equal size orbiting on either side of the planet would work, but not sure...

Edit -
The planet is in reality a space ship with an habitable exterior. The race is capable of artificial gravity and fusion. I Need a sun and moon object in the sky to replicate the appearance of an earth environ on the surface of the ship.

I need to know the minimal distance/size that i could make these from the ship to create the illusion.

Comment: You should have the planet orbit the moon and then have the sun orbit the planet, but not the moon.  That seems like it would work  \s

Comment: By definition a "rouge" planet is unbound, in otherwords its not bound to a sun, which is why its rouge.

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with just having the ship orbit a sun when it doesn't need to move around?

Comment: Your original question made no mention of the *goal* you had (a sky like Earth for your ship inhabitants) or even of the "ship".  This is such a drastic change you should close your question entirely and ask a completely new one (more carefully explained !).  An edit is inappropriate in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the edit is too drastic a change and would completely void the two existing answers made in good faith.

Comment: A rogue planet, a normal planet or a spaceship?

Comment: StephenG If you are voting to close the question because its edit has been too drastic, then you cannot do so in good faith. The question remains about worldbuilding, therefore it cannot be off-topic. What you are doing exercising a punitive vote. It would be better to downvote instead. While it is a pity two answers have been invalidated by the edit, it is better to admonish the OP not to do this again. VTCing is a pile driver to crack a nut. Not the nice way to do things here.

Comment: Actually, the Question didn't change, but I was first to add the edit because of the two answers not understanding that it is a artificial structure which is obvious. II just had to make explicit something that should have been understood implicitly, but whatever. Neither of the answers are actually answers to what they think the question is either  anyways.

Comment: @Durakken - A star is by definition several times more massive than even a giant planet, and so a tiny mars-sized planet will orbit a star.  Therefore the "sun" cannot be a star.  It has to be a giant light emitting machine in order to both be less massive than the planet and thus orbit the planet and also to serve the functions of a sun.  The "sun" must be a giant generator and lamp in order to orbit the planet - sort of like the sun in the First Age of Middle-earth, but technological instead of magic.

Answer (score 11):

Any self sustaining star will be way more massive than Mars. This makes impossible for the star to orbit the planet: it will always be the planet to orbit the star.

Or, better, the center of mass of the system will always be deep into the star.

Answer (score 2):

Change your inertial frame of reference.

If you treat the Earth as a stationary object, then the Sun will be orbiting the Earth roughly once a day. This will make the math needed to explain the motion of the other planets much more complicated, because the motion of the planets will change from being roughly elliptical to a spiral-thing (as can be seen in [this image](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7a02d2273a54313cb8e36acd917903ff)).